# AsyncTask doInBackground stops... no exception thrown

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I created a class within my UI thread called FetchTaskList which extends AsyncTask.
I am using server sockets and trying to read from the input stream of the socket.
When debugging, doInBackground just stops after the while loop finishes, hence onPostExecute is never called. Why is this happening? I have been breaking my head on this for days...

**TaskListActivity.java**

```
private class FetchTaskList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray> {

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(DEFAULT_HOST, DEFAULT_PORT);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            while(scanner.hasNext())
            {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(scanner.nextLine());
                jArray.put(json);
            }
            return jArray;
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG", "I got an error", e);

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG", "I got an error", e);

        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG", "I got an error", e);

        }
        return jArray;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray list) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj = list.getJSONObject(i);
                taskList.add(new Task(obj.get("author").toString(),obj.get("description").toString(),(Date)obj.get("due"),(Task.Priority)obj.get("priority"),(Task.Status)obj.get("status")));
            } 
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG", "I got an error", e);
            }
        }
        ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taskListView);
        TaskListAdapter theAdapter = new TaskListAdapter(taskList,getApplicationContext());
        view.setAdapter(theAdapter);
        view.invalidate();
    }

}
```

EDIT: I don't get anything in LogCat, so no exceptions are caught.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(scanner.hasNext())
```

should be:

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
```

Comment: That's only parsing 2 out of 3 of my JSONobjects on the server... could it be related to that?